# Error: cannot_parse_bock_header

Tags: baking, rpc, error, inject, block

Does anyone know, if this error means that is a bad block? or that i'm doing something wrong?

**The error happens when I try to Inject a Block.**

```
[{"kind":"permanent","id":"validator.invalid_block","invalid_block":"BL6u6y3xWjw35nNTL7g6ayW8npVz1KHbZc3SwCguRiW9ghf9rPL","error":"cannot_parse_bock_header"}]
```

Cannot find this error at http://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/api/errors.html

Comment: Can you please provide more details on what you are doing ? How did you forge this block etc

Comment: I think the problem was because I was creating an invalid protocol_data on shell_header and then sending it to `/chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/forge_block_header`. Should be fixed now.

Comment: glad you solved your problem. Would you mind posting your solution as a full answer so we know the problem is resolved ? We keep track of open questions so making sure the problem is solved is important. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved!

The issue was because of an invalid **proof of work nonce** that I was creating and it failed when I tried to inject the block.

I was inserting non hexadecimal characters in the header.